# How to view directory inside android/data in android 13 - using getExternalStorageDirectory() of Flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, directory

I am using getExternalStorage()function and getting its path in flutter and creating a directory.

/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.project_orphans/files/mydirector/1703165736342_image_picker8316745988776372937.jpg

But when am opening this path in my android device I can't see there file or directory inside android /data

am getting a  message displayed on screen

Due to Android restrictions, the contents of this folder can be shown on a computer.
am using android 13 and Samsung device.

android.manifestfile

```
 <!--   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="33" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="33"  />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
```

function to save image file

```
Future<void> downloadAndSaveImage(String imageUrl, String directoryName) async {
  // Create a directory if it doesn't exist
  Directory? directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  String fullPath = join(directory!.path, directoryName);
  await Directory(fullPath).create(recursive: true);

  // Fetch the image
  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(imageUrl));
  Uint8List bytes = response.bodyBytes;

  // Save the image to the directory
  String fileName = basename(imageUrl);
  String filePath = join(fullPath, fileName);
  File file = File(filePath);
  await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
  print('Image saved to: $filePath');
}
```

Comment: `have create a directory using getExternalStorage() ` Impossible. Such functions do not create directories. And this function does not even exist. Well not in Java. Strange Flutter.

Comment: @blackapps I am getting path by using getExternalStorage() ands creating directory using create() function.
Thanks